# iOS - is possible to record audio from Bluetooth headset mic and play in device speaker

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, bluetooth

I am trying to record audio by Bluetooth headset mic and play by device speaker.
I have seen few stack-overflow post regrading the same but still i am not getting is this possible or not ? and if possible then how to do it? if someone have any idea please inform me.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. Use bluetooth option when setting audio session category.

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
_ = try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .allowBluetooth)
_ = try? audioSession.setActive(true)
```